# Azure Business Glossary in Purview

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-purview, glossary

I would like to create new business term template in azure business glossary of purview via PyApacheAtlas. Which function or code or object should I use for that?
This is my code.

> from pyapacheatlas.core.glossary import AtlasGlossaryTerm
>
> ## Define the term attributes for the term template
>
> term_template_attributes = {
> "description": "This is a term template for creating new terms.",
> "category": "Template",
> # Add more attributes as needed }
>
> ## Create a new glossary term as the term template

```
term_template = AtlasEntity(
typeName="TermTemplate",  
qualified_name="term_template",
name="Term Template"
glossaryGuid: default_glossary["guid"],
attributes=term_template_attributes
```

)

## Upload the term entity to Azure Purview

> client.upload_entities(term_template)

But it is adding as an asset, if it right way how can i use it as a term template? else which type or function should i use for adding a template in business glossary

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share blockers/error details.

Comment: i did. this is my code.